# Get current user's extra information by thymeleaf sec tag working with spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm using **thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4** with spring security on my project. The problem is I cannot get user's extra fields (which means user information on database except `username`, `password`, `enabled`, etc. given by `UserDetails`) by using `<span sec:authentication="principal.something" />`.

Heres are my simple codes:

## UserEntity (implements UserDetails)

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "myschema")
public class UserEntity implements UserDetails {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private int id;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 64)
  private String username;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
  private String password;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BIT")
  private boolean enabled;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "phone", nullable = false, length = 16)
  private String phone;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<AuthorityEntity> authorities;

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return enabled;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return enabled;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return enabled;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return username;
  }
}
```

## AuthorityEntity (implements GrantedAuthority)

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "authorities", schema = "myschema",
    uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id", "authority"}))
public class AuthorityEntity implements GrantedAuthority {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private int id;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "authority", nullable = false, length = 24)
  private String authority;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
  private UserEntity user;
}
```

## UserRepository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Integer> {
  UserEntity findOneByUsernameAndEnabledTrue(String username);
}
```

## UserService

```
@Service
public class UserService {
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Autowired
  public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
  }

  public UserEntity loadUserByUsername(String username) {
    return userRepository.findOneByUsernameAndEnabledTrue(username);
  }
}
```

## SecurityService (extends UserDetailService)

```
@Service
public class SecurityService implements UserDetailsService {
  private UserService userService;

  @Autowired
  public SecurityService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
  }

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserDetails user = userService.loadUserByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
      throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

## SecurityConfig (extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  private SecurityService securityService;

  @Autowired
  public SecurityConfig(SecurityService securityService) {
    this.securityService = securityService;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/user/login").anonymous()
          .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
          .and()
        .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/user/login")
          .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
          .and()
        .logout()
          .logoutUrl("/user/logout")
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
          .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
          .accessDeniedPage("/error/403");
  }

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    auth.userDetailsService(securityService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
  }
}
```

## index.html (using thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4"
      layout:decorator="layout/base">

<th:block layout:fragment="content">
    <h1>Main Page</h1>
    <p sec:authentication="principal.username">Username</p>
    <p sec:authentication="principal.phone">Phone</p>
</th:block>
```

## The Problem

In `index.html`, `sec:authentication="principal.username"` works as expected, but `sec:authentication="principal.phone"` does not despite my `UserDetailsService` implementation stores `UserEntry` which implements `UserDetails` with extra field `phone`.

## Questions

- Is there any way to make `sec:authentication="principal.phone"` work well? (or `"princiapl.getPhone()"` respectively)
- If not, can I get current user's phone number in my thymeleaf without passing it through controller?
- If not, how can I pass current user's `UserEntry` object without plugging model explicitly for instance through `mav` of each controller method? Does AOP deal with this?

**(Additional)** In many other examples applying spring security, they don't implement `UserDetails` on `UserEntry` (or similar classes), but make a new `UserDetails` instance in their `UserDetailService` implementation like

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserInfo activeUserInfo = userInfoDAO.getActiveUser(userName);
    GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(activeUserInfo.getRole());
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails)new User(activeUserInfo.getUserName(),
            activeUserInfo.getPassword(), Arrays.asList(authority));
    return userDetails;
}
```

([from here](http://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-mvc-security-custom-login-and-logout-thymeleaf-csrf-mysql-database-jpa-hibernate-example#security)). I think my structure is not a good design but I don't know exactly why. Is there any comment for my class design?

## Thanks!

If my questions are too vague, let me know so then I would update this more concrete.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use additional fields contained in your user's data in `Thymeleaf`, you must go through the next steps.

1. Implement your own Spring Security's user.
2. Override `loadUserByUsername`, so that it returns your custom user.
3. Add the Spring Security's Thymeleaf Extras dependencies.
4. Use `${#authentication.getPrincipal()}`, instead of `sec`.

**STEP 1**

```
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

import java.util.Collection;

// Our own implementation of the Spring Security User.

public class MyUser extends User {

    // Here we add the extra fields of our users.
    private String phone;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyUser(String username,
                      String password,
                      Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities,
                      String phone) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return realName;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

}
```

**STEP 2**

```
@Override
public MyUser loadUserByUsername(String userName)
        throws AuthenticationException {

    // Fetch the user.
    UserDetails user = userService.loadUserByUsername(username);

    // For each user's authority, add it into our authorities' collection.
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new LinkedList<GrantedAuthority>(); 
    if (user.getAuthorities().size() > 0){
        for (Authority authority : user.getAuthorities()) {
            // Add a new GrantedAuthority for each user's authorities.
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getAuthority()));
         }
    }

    return new MyUser(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities, user.getPhone());
}
```

**STEP 3**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**STEP 4**

```
<th:block th:with="auth=${#authentication.getPrincipal()}">
    <p th:text="${auth ? auth.phone : 'NULL'}">Phone</p>
</th:block>
```

Comment: I think you could also use `sec` instead `authentication.getPrincipal()` like this `<div sec:authentication="principal.phone"></div>`

Comment: But if i use 'extends User' and extend spring security user, i can't create an empty user with no username and password. It says values cannot be null or empty. But i need that empty user for sign up form. How can i resolve this?